# Can't install php with Homebrew on MacOS Mojave

Tags: php, homebrew, reinstall, pax

When I run `brew install php` I get this error:

> tar: Ignoring malformed pax extended attribute tar: Ignoring malformed pax extended attribute tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors. Error: Failure while executing; /usr/bin/env tar --extract --no-same-owner --file /Users/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/592c007136b235b78c9fa8eafda449719cdea58e2a4afe18b9a445cd0050ba1b--doxygen-1.9.7.src.tar.gz --directory /private/tmp/d20230608-43989-1hef8mk exited with 1. Here's the output: tar: Ignoring malformed pax extended attribute tar: Ignoring malformed pax extended attribute tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.

I don't know how to fix this. I already reinstalled Homebrew but that doesn't help.

It is not clear to me how to fix the error and get the latest version of php.

I tried everything in Google, all the commands.

I have MacOS Mojave.

Comment: can you try clearing the caches at `/Users/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads`?

Comment: Sounds like that downloaded archive is corrupt. Either an issue with the download, or someone tempered with the source.